# Cakephp auth login issue. Can I use ClientController for login?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am currently setting up a login module in site which have two role like admin,normal user.
UsersController already created for backend login and it's working.
I have created another controller ClientController and created new table client in database.

But login is not working and giving error username and password is incorrect.
I have to use UsersController for login.
Here is the code I am using.

thanks in advance for your help!

**AppController.php :**

```
public $components = array(
'Acl',
'Auth' => array(
    'authorize' => array(
    'Actions' => array(
        'actionPath' => 'controllers',
        'userModel' => 'Clients '
        )
    ),
    'authError' => 'Sorry, you are not authorised to do that.',
),
'Session'
);
```

**ClientController.php :**

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login() {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Your login was successful.');
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'dashboard'));
        }

        $this->Session->setFlash('Your username or password was incorrect. Please, try again.');
        return $this->redirect('/login');
    }
    }
```

**Client.php**
**model**

```
    class Client extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'clients';
    public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'required' => array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        'message' => 'A username is required'
        )
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        'message' => 'A password is required'
        )
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'email' => array(
        'rule' => array('email', true),
        'message' => 'Please supply a valid email address.'
        ),
        'required' => array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        'message' => 'A email is required'
        )
    )
    );
    public $belongsTo = array(
    'Group' => array(
        'className' => 'Group',
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

    if (empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        unset($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    } else {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need to set auth components again in ClientController and also need to specify method of Authentication with userModel.

*for example in your case:*

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Form' => array('userModel' => 'Client')
        );
```

put above code in **ClientController**'s **beforeFilter** method.